# Problems with execvp() and/or strings , why this code does not work?

Tags: c, linux, shell, exec, strtok

I wrote this code that opens a file and executes every line of files exept comment "#":

myfile:

```
ls -l
ls -a
cat /tmp/filex
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void run(const char *cmd, const char *arg){
    char *argv[3];
    asprintf(&argv[0],"%s", cmd);
    asprintf(&argv[1], "%s", arg);
    argv[2] = NULL;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        execvp(argv[0], (char * const *) argv);
        perror("error: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}

void scriptexec(FILE *fp){
    char *line = NULL, *cmd = NULL, *arg=NULL, *delim=" \n\t";
    size_t len = 0;
    while(getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1){
        cmd = strtok_r(line, delim, &arg);
        if(cmd[0] != '#')
            run(cmd, arg);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc < 2) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r" )) == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    scriptexec(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

$ ./a.out file

I get this output:

```
ls: invalid option -- '
'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
ls: invalid option -- '
'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
cat: /tmp/filex
: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to write another code using the run() function, it works, no problems!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void run(const char *cmd, const char *arg){
    char *argv[3];
    asprintf(&argv[0],"%s", cmd);
    asprintf(&argv[1], "%s", arg);
    argv[2] = NULL;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        execvp(argv[0], (char * const *) argv);
        perror("error: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}

int main(){
    run("ls", "-l");
}
```

I can't understand...

Comment: I doubt code is running out of memory, yet `argv[0]`, `argv[1]`, `line`  should be free'd.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the (non-working) program in a debugger to check what happens, while monitoring all variables and their values? Please take some time to [read about how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Pay attention to the position of the quotes. You have LF chars where you shouldn't . `ls` is saying the option `<LF>` is not a valid option. `cat` says it can't find `/tmp/filex<LF>`

Comment: @ikegami Nice.  I suppose code should not execute every _line_.

Comment: Note: `cmd = strtok_r(line, delim, &arg);
        if(cmd[0] != '#')` is a problem should `strtok_r()` return `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls: invalid option -- '
'
```

See the two single-quotes. There is a new-line being passed to `ls`, which is indeed an "invalid option".

`getline()` returns the new-line, the input had been triggered with.

Just chop it off, if around, before passing on what had been read.

To do so you can use this:

```
line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = '\0';
```